# ng-repeat over an array of objects (how to get the object of the event clicked)

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have an array of objects that I am trying to display. I am passing in the object to the directive like this:

```
 <td ng-repeat-start="(key,dept) in time" editable-field time="dept">{{times[$index][key].start}}</td>
 <td ng-repeat-end>{{times[$index][key].end}}</td>
```

My table is structured like this:

### Business Hours

```
     <table class="table table-bordered">
        <thead>
         <tr>
           <th></th>
           <th style="vertical-align:top" scope="col" colspan="2">Sales</th>
           <th style="vertical-align:top" scope="col" colspan="2" >Service</th>
           <th style="vertical-align:top" scope="col" colspan="2">Parts</th>
           <th style="vertical-align:top" scope="col" colspan="2">Accounting</th>
           <th style="vertical-align:top" scope="col" colspan="2">Body Shop</th>
           <th style="vertical-align:top" scope="col" colspan="2" >Other</th>
         </tr>
         </thead>
           <tr ng-repeat="time in times">
                 <td>{{weekdays[$index]}}</td>

                 <td ng-repeat-start="(key,dept) in time" editable-field time="dept">td>
                 <td ng-repeat-end>td>
```

My controller:

```
    .controller("businessHours", function($scope) {
   $scope.weekdays = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday","Sunday"];
  $scope.departments = ["sales", "service","accounting","bodyshop","other"];

  $scope.times = [];
  $.each($scope.weekdays, function(index, value) {
    var dayTimes = {};
    $.each($scope.departments, function(index, value){
      dayTimes[value] = {start: '5', end: '6'};
    });
    $scope.times.push(dayTimes);
  });


})
```

The table I have built displays the business hours of a company. The user can click a cell inside the table and update the time. The problem I am facing is I am unable to get the object that the user has clicked. I would like to use the two way binding that I have setup in my scope using "=".  I know there are other ways of getting this to work, but I am trying to follow the best practice. Can anyone please point me in the right direction.

```
fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kjodqdos/75/


 <!--- Updated -->
```

I am able to get the event, but I am unsure on where the actual object is.

```
m.Event {originalEvent: MouseEvent, type: "click", timeStamp: 6290.860000000001, jQuery111109128661639738198: true, toElement: td.ng-binding.ng-scope.ng-isolate-scope…}
```

Answer (score 0):

pass $event in ng-click action like `ng-click="yourfunction($event)"`

Comment: I attempted that. But I don't actually see the object that was clicked.

Comment: In my case i want to get button event
  angular.module('app', []).controller('ctrl', function ($scope) {
        $scope.aa = function (sender)
        {
            console.log(sender.target)

        }
    })
        <button type="button" ng-click="aa($event)">Click</button> 

Try this

Comment: I'm sorry could you create me a fiddle. I had trouble getting it to work.

Comment: Pass the object itself, not the $event.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `event.srcElement.innerHTML` to access the clicked cell, here's an example.I hope that it helps:

```
.directive("editableField", function($timeout){
    return {
    restrict: 'A',
    template: '<td style="table-layout:fixed;"  ng-click="showInputBox($event);hideSavedTime()">{{time.start}}</td>', 
    //weeksdays is empty here because of the isolated scope
    replace:false,
    scope: {
        time: '='
    },

    controller: function($scope) {
        console.log($scope.time);

       $scope.showInputBox = function(event){

            var cell = event.srcElement.innerHTML;
                alert('Cell value - ' + cell);
       }

    }
  }
})
```